# How to perform DNS lookup with multiple questions?

Tags: testing, dns, packet-injection

DNS standard allows for specifying more than 1 question per query (I mean inside single DNS packet). I'm writing Snort plugin for DNS analyzis and I need to test whether it behaves properly when there's DNS query containing multiple questions.

DNS packet structure looks like this:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F 
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      ID                       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    QDCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ANCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    NSCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ARCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|         <ACTUAL QUESTIONS GO HERE>            |
|                                               |
|                     ...                       |
|                                               |
```

So if `QDCOUNT` is greater than 1 there can be multiple DNS questions in single query.

How can I perform such query using linux tools? `dig domain1.example domain2.example` creates just 2 separate queries with 1 question each. `host` and `nslookup` seem to allow querying only 1 name at the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this question for the full details: [Requesting A and AAAA records in single DNS query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082081/requesting-a-and-aaaa-records-in-single-dns-query/4083071#4083071)

In short, no actually no one today does multiple questions in a single query. This was never clearly defined, and poses a lot of questions (like: there is only a single return code so what do you do for 2 questions if one failed and not the other?).

It would have been useful for people to do `A` and `AAAA` queries at the same time (instead of the deprecated `ANY`) but it basically does not exist today.

Comment: Interesting. It led to more questions than aswered though. If such queries are barely supported by anything I think IPS/IDS should see them as really really suspicious activity or even just plain always drop them without further analysis...

Comment: @Lapsio I think I agree for IDS, at least that is probably suspicious nowadays since no server I suppose will handle them anyway.

Comment: Interesting.  I was wondering why Cloudflare (1.1.1.1.1) and my local ISP does not support ANY DNS queries while Google (8.8.8.8) does.  Didn't know that it was deprecated.

Comment: @lafolle: About `ANY` deprecation: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8482

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks for the followup,  thats pretty recent development for ANY query!

Comment: Cloudflare was very vocal about it: https://blog.cloudflare.com/deprecating-dns-any-meta-query-type/ (2015) and https://blog.cloudflare.com/what-happened-next-the-deprecation-of-any/ (2016). This gave the RFC written in part by Cloudflare people.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve all the records from a zone using a single `AXFR` request, and then parse out the ones you want.

```
dig @127.0.0.1 domain.com. AXFR
```

or

```
nslookup -query=AXFR domain.com 127.0.0.1
```

Typically `AXFR` requests are refused except for slave servers, so you will need to whitelist IPs that are allowed to make this request.   (In bind this is done with the `allow-transfer` option).

This won't work for OP's use case of making a snort plugin that checks QDCOUNT but it does kind of solve the problem of sending multiple questions in a single DNS request.

source: [serverfault: How to request/acquire all records from a DNS?](https://serverfault.com/a/117971/)